# Element spinner must be declared

Tags: android, layout, spinner

I'm trying to add Spinner to ActionBar and getting this error right in xml file:

```
Element spinner must be declared
```

[image]

I'm confused. The problem solution must be simple but I can't really realize how to solve it..

Comment: Where is your layout ; LinearLayout , RelativeLayout etc..

Comment: it has to be inside a parent layout

Comment: when I wrap it into layout it shows the same error but for parent: e.g `element LinearLayout must be declared`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to put a `Spinner` in your menu XML. Views such as Spinners are not valid elements in menus.

If you intent to inflate this layout and use it in an Activity or Fragment, you should move this file to `/layouts`. If you are actually trying to get a Spinner in your ActionBar, I recommend reading the [Adding Drop-down Navigation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Dropdown) documentation.

In your Activity's `onCreate()` you will need to call `setNavigationMode(NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST)`, then `actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(mSpinnerAdapter, mNavigationCallback)`, passing in a `SpinnerAdapter` and an `ActionBar.OnNavigationListener`.